Power BI: вывести список лучших сотрудников за период
Доброй ночи, дамы и господа!
Вопрос по Power BI.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу настроить вывод списка сотрудников (ФИО) при выборе определенного квартала в срезе (2023-2024 года), которые в течение всех трёх месяцев имели бы коэф. от 0.8 до 1.0?
Пример данных (2024 год):



ФИО
Месяц
Коэф.




Иванов
Январь
1.0


Иванов
Февраль
1.0


Иванов
Март
0.8


Любимова
Январь
0.9


Любимова
Февраль
0.3


Любимова
Март
0.3


Сидоров
Январь
0.8


Сидоров
Февраль
0.8


Сидоров
Март
0.6



Возможно, к этой задаче можно подойти со стороны редактирования SQL запроса (postgresql).
Заранее благодарю за помощь.

которые в течение всех трёх месяцев имели бы коэф. от 0.8 до 1.0? Сформулируйте так: у которых нет в это период коэффициента менее 0.8. Из него сразу выплывает очевидный WHERE NOT EXISTS.

На SQL запрос может выглядеть так:
select p.namePreson -- Покажи ФИО
from persons p -- из таблицы
where p.koef >= 0.8 -- где коэф больше или равен 0.8
and p.month in ('Январь', 'Февраль', 'Март') -- и месяца такието
group by p.namePreson -- сгруппируй по ФИО
having count(*) = 3 -- Верни где строк 3

Сам запрос выведет ФИО, где в указанные месяца есть 3 записи с коэф >= 0.8
Пример в песочнице
